# Adminer - can't allow for larger file uploads than 2mb

Tags: apache-http-server, php, php.ini

I'm trying to upload my db dump file through adminer, but it is limited to 2MB uploads, even though I went to the php.ini file and chenged it to 35MB.

I'm using a vagrant php environment generated by puphpet.com.

I tried calling phpinfo() to check that I was editing the currently loaded php.ini. I was (/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini). I checked all of the "additional .ini files parsed" for an upload_max_filesize entry with no results. Still, the phpinfo tells me that the file-size is set to 2MB - no matter what directory on my webserver I run it from.

How might this be solved?

Comment: Did you force php to reload following the change to phprc... something like `killall php.cgi` YMMV on the exact command based on how the php was compiled.

Comment: I restarted apache. Should that not be sufficient for the changes to kick in?

Comment: restarting apache would not cause a change to php.ini to be read, you would need to let php respawn itself. unless the machine is extremely busy, it probably happaned naturally overnight... check your phpinfo again now.  FWIW there are also client (browser) side size limitations.  Do you not have SSH or SFTP access?  those protocols would be much more efficient for a one-time large size upload.